# CachedNetworkImage sometimes does not show loaded image unless you interact with the view

Tags: flutter

[image: Action in question]

As you can see on GIF, `CachedNetworkImage()` sometimes does not show the loaded image, unless you interact with the page. Please help me figure out why this is happening and how to fix it?

[Imgur link for better resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwEnC.jpg)

```
SizedBox _buildImage(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned.fill(
            child: CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: event.pictureUrl,
              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
                return Ink.image(
                  image: imageProvider,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  child: Container(),
                );
              },
              progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          value: downloadProgress.progress,
                          color: Colors.black38,
                        )),
                  ],
                );
              },
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
                // ignore: avoid_print
                print(error);
                return Image.asset('assets/images/error.png');
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [
                  Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.0),
                  Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                ],
                stops: const [0.9, 1],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by changing `Ink.image(...)` imageBuilder return to:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: imageProvider,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Which, theoretically, should be the same. But the issue is now gone.

Please, answer the question if you have details on the issue I'll accept an explaination of this behaviour.